# Why was this question put on hold for off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold-questions

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613264/xy-for-small-values-of-x-and-y-the-op-has-requested-that-this-question-b

But it should be put on hold for duplicate. Why on hold for off-topic? It is clearly about math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initiated the close vote, and selected the reason "not about mathematics." The original asker had blanked the post, editing it with a message about a desired that the question be deleted; since it wasn't a question anymore, I voted to close it as not on-topic.

Another user has since reverted the edits and restored the content in the question, and so I agree that closure-as-duplicate would be a better option. As far as I know, the only way to change the closure reason would be to reopen the question and then close it again. Since I doubt that it would be possible to find 5 users to vote to reopen, I'd suggest flagging the question for a moderator and linking to a proposed duplicate; they can open and close questions unilaterally.

Comment: I'll check for the edit history next time. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. last time I saw you at 4k back in august.. what an improvement!

Comment: I've reopened it and closed it as a duplicate now.

Comment: When a user blanks a question, you should not vote to close based on the new version, but roll back to the original.